# Blackberry send a HTTPPost request

Tags: blackberry

i am developing and app for blackberry and i need to send a Http Post Request to my server. I'm using the simulator in order to test my app and i found this code in order to send request:

http://vasudevkamath.techfiz.com/general/posting-data-via-http-from-blackberry/

But i can't get it work, because it fails in this line:

```
int rc = _httpConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What happens at this line?

Comment: Yes, what is happening? Also, are you invoking the method postData() on the event thread, or do you start up a separate thread? HTTP access on the event thread will cause problems.

Comment: Also getting this problem. Thread (not UI) waits at `httpConn.getResponseCode();` for awhile then exits with Exception: `java.io.InterruptedIOException: Local connection timed out after ~ 120000`. Server is accessible from the browser on the simulator. I'm using code similar to the answers below. @xger86x did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code on how to send a POST request:

```
HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
OutputStream os = c.openOutputStream();
os.write(request.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();
os.close();
InputStream is = c.openInputStream();
```

Just make sure you use this code in a separate thread.

Comment: How do you set POST parameters?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static ResponseBean sendRequestAndReceiveResponse(String method, String absoluteURL, String bodyData, boolean readResponseBody) 
throws IOException
{
    ResponseBean responseBean = new ResponseBean();
    HttpConnection httpConnection = null;

    try
    {

        String formattedURL = absoluteURL + "deviceside=true;interface=wifi"; // If you are using WiFi
        //String formattedURL = absoluteURL + "deviceside=false"; // If you are using BES
        //String formattedURL = absoluteURL + "deviceside=true"; // If you are using TCP

        if(DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) // if you are using simulator
            formattedURL = absoluteURL;

        httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(formattedURL);

        httpConnection.setRequestMethod(method);

        if (bodyData != null && bodyData.length() > 0)
        {                               
            OutputStream os = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
            os.write(bodyData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }           

        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        responseBean.setResponseCode(responseCode);

        if (readResponseBody)
        {
            responseBean.setBodyData(readBodyData(httpConnection));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {                       
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! IOException in NetworkUtil::sendRequestAndReceiveResponse(): " + ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {                       
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Exception in NetworkUtil::sendRequestAndReceiveResponse(): " + ex);
        throw new IOException(ex.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (httpConnection != null)
            httpConnection.close();
    }

    return responseBean;
}

public static StringBuffer readBodyData(HttpConnection httpConnection) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException
{   
    if(httpConnection == null)
        return null;

    StringBuffer bodyData = new StringBuffer(256);                          
    InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.openDataInputStream();

    byte[] data = new byte[256];
    int len = 0;
    int size = 0;

    while ( -1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
    {
        bodyData.append(new String(data, 0, len,"UTF-8"));
        size += len;
    }

    if (inputStream != null)
    {
        inputStream.close();            
    }

    return bodyData;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to invoke this method in a separate thread and before updating UI you must get eventLock using Application.getUiApplication.getEventLock();

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old and OP probably solved it by now, but I've just run into the same problem and managed to fix it!

**You need to append `;deviceside=true` to your URL.**

So for example, your URL will change from `"http://example.com/directory/submitpost.php"` to `"http://example.com/directory/submitpost.php;deviceside=true"`.

I found this here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879

My POST request was timing out after 3 minutes when I did not have this (See [My Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005648/blackberry-send-a-httppost-request#comment15816959_5005648)), but it works fine with this appended to the url.

I would also recommend using `ConnectionFactory`. Here's some of my code:

```java
Network.httpPost("http://example.com/directory/submitpost.php;deviceside=true", paramNamesArray, paramValsArray)
```

```java
public static void httpPost(String urlStr, String[] paramName, String[] paramVal) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        conFactory.setTimeLimit(1000);
        HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) conFactory.getConnection(urlStr).getConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) {
            sb.append(paramName[i]);
            sb.append("=");
            sb.append(paramVal[i]);
            sb.append("&");
        }
        byte[] postData = sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",new Integer(postData.length).toString());

        OutputStream out = conn.openOutputStream();
        out.write(postData);
        //out.flush();      //Throws an Exception for some reason/Doesn't do anything anyways
        out.close();

        //This writes to our connection and waits for a response 
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new Exception(conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the site you posted, but I've successfully used the sample ConnectionFactory code provided on the blackberry site.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-Code-Using-the-ConnectionFactory-class-in-a-BrowserField/ta-p/532860

Just make sure not to invoke the connection on the EventThread.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you add parameters, Full answer is here:

```
StringBuffer postData = new StringBuffer();

                    httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("https://surveys2.kenexa.com/feedbacksurveyapi/login?");
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

                    postData.append("username="+username);
                    postData.append("&password="+pass);
                    postData.append("&projectcode="+projectid);
                    String encodedData = postData.toString();

                    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",(new Integer(encodedData.length())).toString());
                    byte[] postDataByte = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                    OutputStream out = httpConn.openOutputStream(); 
                    out.write(postDataByte);
                    out.close();

                    httpConn.getResponseCode();
```